# Upgrading an app to Rails 3.1.0.beta1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm attempting to update my existing rails app (3.0.3) to 3.1.0.beta1. I've install the rails gem and ran the `bundle` command to pull in all of the updated gems. When I run `rake rails:update` though I get:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `join_asset_file_contents' for module `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Trace Output**

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `join_asset_file_contents' for module `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.beta1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.beta1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/smurf-1.0.6/lib/smurf.rb:15:in `<module:AssetTagHelper>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/smurf-1.0.6/lib/smurf.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `block in run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

**After removing the Smurf Gem**

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb:7)
** Invoke rails:update (first_time)
** Invoke rails:update:configs (first_time)
** Execute rails:update:configs
    conflict  config/boot.rb
Overwrite /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/boot.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] y
       force  config/boot.rb
       exist  config
    conflict  config/routes.rb
Overwrite /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/routes.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip  config/routes.rb
    conflict  config/application.rb
Overwrite /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] y
       force  config/application.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
** Invoke rails:update:javascripts (first_time)
** Execute rails:update:javascripts
rake aborted!
undefined method `create_javascript_files' for #<Rails::Generators::AppGenerator:0x00000100fbb160>
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake:40:in `invoke_from_app_generator'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join_asset_file_contents method is moved from

```
actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb
```

to

```
actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helpers/asset_include_tag.rb
```

That is the reason why you see this error.

Can you please run the rake command with --trace to see why join_asset_file_contents is being executed in the call graph?

Comment: Perfect. You are using [smurf](https://github.com/thumblemonks/smurf) for doing js and css minification which is not updated to yet to support rails 3.1. Please remove the smurf dependency for now and try again.

Comment: I removed that and now I get further in the process but now I'm getting a different error. I have added the new trace.

Comment: The other stack trace that you had posted seems to be an error in 3.1.0.beta1 version. It has been fixed couple of days back in the master rails branch. The following diff shows the change [9d8ce55e062a23461e1ec81ba559bfa3fc3b7ca8](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d8ce55e062a23461e1ec81ba559bfa3fc3b7ca8) To fix the problem please update your gem file to work with the rails master or you need to wait for the next version of the rails 3.1

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I'll just wait for the next beta version.